# HTML on Google Chrome doesn't show my image

Tags: html, image, google-chrome

When trying to view an index.html file in the browser, it doesn't show any images. I get a broken image icon.

I inspected page and got the following error:

> Failed to load resource: net:: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

The *image* is in an *image folder* (i.e. images) located in the *main folder* (i.e. test-site)

I tried on multiple browsers: Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My test page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="\test-site\images\japanese.png" alt="My test image">
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to show this *image*. However, a broken image icon shows but no image...

> error: Failed to load resource: net:: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly accessing the file path? Change the file path to have forward slashes `/` instead of backward slashes `\\` and try again.

Comment: It seems that your path is wrong. Try something like this `./test-site/images/japanese.png` and make sure that you haven't done any typos.

Comment: @AminuKano mentioned slashes.  Is this as windows or *nix based webserver? the local path to the image may also not be the same as the host path to the image.

Comment: both back nor forward slashes worked, the ./test-site/ didn't work either..... this is a windows system (forgot to mention that)

Comment: Try to open image from explorer to browser, if you succeed in that you will definitely show image inside index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the index.html file is inside the test-site folder (main folder), then you do not need to include that in your link as such:

```
 <img src ="./images/japanese.png" alt ="My test Image">
```

Should work for you, as the dot is representative of the folder you are already in.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My test page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="./test-site/images/japanese.png" alt="My test image">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the index.html file is inside the test-site folder (main folder), then you do not need to include that in your link as such:

It should work for you

Comment: the image is located in my images folder inside the main folder.. index.html is also in the main folder

Comment: Ok.So you need to make sure put correct path but just put .. before starting any path.

Answer (score 0):

if your image and index.html are on the same folder then

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <img src="./images/japanese.png" alt="My test image">
      <!-- or  ->
      <img src="images/japanese.png" alt="My test image">
 
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: neither of these worked, checked spelling and all spelling is the same

Comment: correction: this worked, not sure what i did different to this (was identical when trying everything y'all suggested!)